# Permanent redirect domain to www subdomain without web.config

Tags: redirects, asp.net, iis7, domains, 1and1

I've just set up a site via 1and1 and have run into an issue, I want to accomplish the simple task of  redirecting the root domain to the `www` sub domain however due to complications I cant seam to find a way to get it to work.

I'm on a Microsoft (asp.net) package so can't use *.htaccess*, also the IIS server they have doesn't have the URL redirect module installed (so can't use `<rewrite>` in web.config).

They have built in HTTP forwarding options however if I set the root domain to redirect to the `www` sub domain it just infinitely redirects.

Hopefully there is some obvious option/method I've missed during the past two days of searching!

Answer (score 1):

*You can redirect using VBScript*

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
' Permanent redirection
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader "Location", "http://www.domain.com/"
Response.End
%>
```

*You can also use JavaScript*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href='http://www.domain.com/';
</script>
```

*Or finally redirection with META Refresh HTML*

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.domain.com/">`